# Nodejs custom class won't render in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

I apologise in advance for what is probably a really obvious fix..

I'm trying to render the output from an mssql stored procedure (multiple recordsets) in nodejs using handlebars.

(Also NOT a JS coder, or a coder really)

Challenge 1:
The SP provides data in a column format, while the graph plugin requires an array for label,x,y..

I though I solved this with a custom class with 3 arrays..

```js
class myClass{
  #X = [];
  #Y = [];
  #Label = [];
  get X { return #X; }
  get Y { return #Y; }
  get Label { return #Label; }
  Add(x,y,label){
    #X.push(x);
    #Y.push(y);
    #Label.push(label);
  }
}
```

But I'm getting something weird (but probably obvious)..

The query returns data as expected and I can loop over it creating a new myClass for each recordset and then adding the values into the arrays, I can also access each property through console.log.

What I can't do is send the object as whole to console, it prints as {myClass {}}.

Challenge 2:
It won't render through handlebars

I suspect that 1 is causing the other, but simply don't know enough to stay for sure.

Any help gratefully received :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it

DON'T USE PRIVATE PROPERTIES...

Neither Handlebars or console.log use the get() function, so if it's private they can't see it...

If you have a similar issue, I hope this helps.